# Change the form of an array (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, bar-chart

I have a huge, complicated issue in my php app. Here are the details:

I currently have this as my array (var dumped):

```
array (size=6)
  0 => string '11/04/15' (length=8)
  1 => string '15/04/15' (length=8)
  2 => string '19/04/15' (length=8)
  3 => string '1' (length=1)
  4 => string '1' (length=1)
  5 => string '3' (length=1)
```

But I want it displayed as:

```
array (size=6)
  array(size=2)
    string '11/04/15' (length=8)
    string '1' (length=1)
  array(size=2)
    string '15/04/15' (length=8)
    string '1' (length=1)
  array(size=2)
    string '19/04/15' (length=8)
    string '3' (length=1)
```

As you can see I would like to add sub arrays, reorder the structure and remove the keys. The starter array values change so there could be more dates/less dates and numbers. Also the its linked, the key 0 should be bulked with key 3 and key 1 bulked with key 4 etc. I think that's enough information.

PS: I'm trying to arrange the data for Chart PHP's Bar Graph (http://www.chartphp.com/).

Comment: Have you tried something? Where is your code?

Comment: @Rizier123 not really as I am totally confused on how I would start.

Comment: You can't get stuck until you try something! So just try something and when you get stuck post it and say: I'm here and I have now ideas how to get further and how to solve it

Comment: @Rizier123 That's true!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

Since it is pretty obvious I'm going to assume, that the pattern behind your expected results should be to combine the numbers with the dates which are sorted ASC.

So here I first get all dates into an array with [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php). Then I also get the numbers by getting the [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) from the original array and the dates array.

Then I sort both arrays ASC and the `$dates` array I sort with [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) where I compare the timestampes which I get with [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and the `$numbers` array I sort simply with [`sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php).

At the end I simply loop through both arrays with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) where I then create the expected result.

```
<?php

    $arr = [
            "19/04/15",
            "11/04/15",
            "15/04/15",
            "3",
            "1",
            "1",
        ];

    $dates = preg_grep("/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/", $arr);
    $numbers = array_diff($arr, $dates);

    sort($numbers);
    usort($dates, function($a, $b){
        if(strtotime($a) == strtotime($b))
            return 0;
        return strtotime($a) < strtotime($b) ? 1 : -1;
    });

    $result = array_map(function($v1, $v2){
        return [$v1, $v2];
    }, $dates, $numbers);

    print_r($result);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11/04/15
            [1] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15/04/15
            [1] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19/04/15
            [1] => 3
        )

)
```

Comment: @Rizier123 why not strtotime($a) - strtotime($b) ? Do i not know something? )

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be the following:

1. Go through the array values with a foreach-loop and find out when the first number starts (in this case, it's the 4. element)
2. Save the number inside of a variable.
3. Create a new array
4. Go through the old array again and get the pairs, then push them into the new array.

The code would be similar to this:

```
<?
$old = array("date1","date2","date3",1,2,3);
$n = null;
foreach($old as $k => $v){
  if(/*CHECK HERE IF $v is NOT A DATE anymore*/){
    $n = $k;
    break;
  }
}
$new = array();
foreach($old as $k => $v){
  if($k < $n){
    $temp = array($v, $old[$k+$n]);
    array_push($new, $temp);
  }
}
var_dump ($new);
?>
```